# require file inside function PHP

Tags: php

I have two classes, class A and class B, and in a function in class A I want to call a function in B, but the it also requires constants from another file. After requiring both the config.php and classB.php files, I am able to create an instance of class B, but when I try to call the function in B, it gives me a warning saying the constant has not been defined.

In config.php:

```
$constant = 'blah';
```

Inside class A I have:

```
function functionA() {
    require_once "config.php";
    require_once "classB.php";
    $b = new B();
    $b -> functionB($constant);
}
```

The call to function B is giving an error saying $constant is not defined, but when I call new B() there is no problem. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: looooks like it should work ..

Comment: Can you provide your PHP version? It seems to run fine in PHP 5.6.13

Comment: Yeah, `$constant` should be defined, but only inside a function in which script which contains it is required. It won't be defined outside that function, for example in different function.

Comment: is that all the content of the config.php file?

Comment: Can you post a bit of classB?

Comment: @DawidFerenczy That's not true. The scope of a constant is global.

Comment: The only way this isn't throwing that error for me, is if config.php is just $constant = "blah" without opening php <?php

Comment: or has a `return 'something';` before `$constant = 'blah';`; or isn't in global scope; or his warning is refers to some other piece of code

Comment: *"it gives me a warning saying the constant has not been defined."* - `$constant` - Just because the variable is called "constant", doesn't define it as a constant; let's get that straight. `define("MAXSIZE", 100);` is a constant, `$constant` is a variable. Let's not mix up those two different animals. You have classes, show them.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I was just typing that up. You beat me to it.

Comment: @Mike Yeah, it's a bad choice of words. That obviously isn't OP's full code, so it's a *free for all* at this point.

Comment: OP: You need to create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Mike Where do you see any constant? I see just a variable.

Comment: @DawidFerenczy You're right. It's just a variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aron is correct. In this case you want to use `include` or `require`. You must make sure that you have no function or class declarations in the files you're including though.

This is occurring because the require will not occur on every call to the method, just the first. The subsequent calls to the method will result in an undefined variable error.

Additional top tip: You can return values from included files to assign them directly to a variable

A.php:

```
return 'abc';
```

B.php:

```
Class B {
    public static function load()
    {
        $x = include 'A.php';
        var_dump($x);
    }
}
```

I imagine that your code should look as follows:

```
function functionA() {
    require "config.php";
    require_once "classB.php";
    $b = new B();
    $b -> functionB($constant);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use the sentence include 'config.php';

instead of require_once, if your config.php file just has variable declarations.